# how to scroll to image at footer that still not rendered?

Tags: javascript, html

### Context

I have an image at the footer of a page like

```
|header|
\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\
|image|
\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\
|footer|
```

To scroll to the said image, I used:

```
image.scrollIntoView()
```

### Issue

But it only works when the image is fully loaded by the browser. However, if the page isn't loaded the page doesn't scroll to it because the image is not yet rendered and does not have right **offset**

It does work, however, when I bind it to `onload` like

```
window.onload = function(){
  image.scrollIntoView()
}
```

This, unfortunately, leads to terrible user experience, because:

- The entire page is loaded except for the image (*Which is still downloading*).
- So the user is already checking the site
- And when the image is fully loaded, then the scroll takes place.
- This is very jarring and is annoying to the user / me because I'd like the page to scroll to it automatically on load time, then check the site (And not check the site for a bit, only for it to suddenly scroll me back to the image)

Comment: try this `image.onload = function(){
  image.scrollIntoView()
}`

Comment: @IvanKaraman same it waits till image full load to scroll to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution - Parent Containers

So in the case of loading your image, you can build a viewer parent element that already has known dimensions, and inside which you can load your image. This image can be:

- Stretched
- Maxed by height/width (and truncated)
- Maxed by height/width (and padded)

Something like:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {
  // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded
  const img = document.querySelector('#MainImage5')
  setTimeout(_ => {
    img.scrollIntoView()
  }, 50)
});
```

```css
figure {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

figure>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ff9800;
  color: white
}

footer {
  background: #4caf50
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>This is the header</h1>
  </header>
  <section class='Main-Content'>
    <ul>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
    </ul>
    <figure id='MainImage'>
      <img src='https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*UEtwA2ask7vQYW06.png'>
    </figure>
    <figure id='MainImage2'>
      <img src='https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/d/c/0/20618.jpg'>
    </figure>
    <figure id='MainImage3'>
      <img src='https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/d/c/0/20618.jpg'>
    </figure>
    <figure id='MainImage4'>
      <img src='https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/d/c/0/20618.jpg'>
    </figure>
    <figure id='MainImage5'>
      <img src='https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/d/c/0/20618.jpg'>
    </figure>
    <ul>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
      <li>Other Point</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <footer>I am the footer</footer>
</body>
```

***Note:*** You can hit **Run Snippet** to see the demo

#### Addendum

To demo that it was indeed scrolling to image, I also buffed up the content above and below the image while keeping your header and footer.

### Explanation

This essentially works by allowing the browser to take its time loading the image, but us constraining it's width to match the container width (with height auto-scaled).

***Edit:*** The container also needs a min-height for scrolling to work correctly, we're using `20px`

Comment: it worked on one picture pages in my site but if i have 5 pictures loading same time like having MainImage1 MainImage2 MainImage3 MainImage4 MainImage5 and want to go to **5** it does same problem and yes changed id to be ("#MainImage5") try with 500px height image

Comment: Updated it to work for your use case, go ahead and give it a try. This time the photo is 4K (for the second image)

Comment: yes but add 5 of the same picture stacked top each other and tell script to scroll to fifth picture then same problem appear and it stay at beggining figure

Comment: Okay adjusted for that case instead, now all images have fixed height, dynamic width

Comment: i think it works because height is fixed 500px but i mean 500px image with height auto